# Does a familiar detect as a specific alignment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, familiars, alignment

Okay, so what I've learned: the table for Detect Evil states that a creature will detect as evil if it has enough hit dice. But familiars are also in some ways an extension of their master.

Let's say an evil wizard has a familiar, a rat for instance. Rats are not inherently evil, but I can't find the rule stating whether their alignment is modified in any way as a magic creature. I have read that they are simply neutral, but I am unable to confirm this.

Also, this may be unlikely but I feel it worth asking if the alignment of the creature's master would automatically reflect instead, as the familiar is, so to speak, a part of him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creature has its own alignment. It registers as that alignment to spells like *detect evil* as if it had hit dice equal to its normal HD, or the master's level, whichever's higher.

> Hit Dice: For the purpose of effects related to number of Hit Dice, use the master's character level or the familiar's normal HD total, whichever is higher.

For example, my LN witch 15 has a LE imp familiar. The imp detects as a LE 15 HD outsider.

Comment: I don't see anyone contradicting you, so I'm going to accept this. It does line up with what I've previously found.